# Json not updating in github repo

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, git, github

So, I have some JSON that is updated while the code is being ran, And I notice that it updates when ran on my machine but not when I host the code, For Hosting I use heroku and I use github as the repository. Im sure it has something to do with a configureation issue as you cannot just update code without commiting it in git, the issue im having is How do I get the JSON to update in github.
I am using Node.js and Fs (filesystem)
Example: code.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
if(true) {
const content = {"name": "joe"};
 fs.writefilesync('./some.json', JSON.stringify(content),{flag: 'w+'});
/* 
on my machine this works perfectly as it should, 
however when i cloud host it, the JSON doesnt update.
*/
};
```

Comment: Is there an error thrown? If so, what is it?

Comment: No there is no error, it simply just doesnt update in github, I image because code cannot be changed without a commit.

Comment: Have you check your git ignore file?

Comment: If the issue did revolve around it, what would I find in my git ignore

Comment: Code can be changed without a commit. A commit is a snapshot, saving the current state of the code. It should never prevent changes. That would be kinda pointless. --- A gitignore file is found in the root of the repo.

Comment: Again I said i would image that being the reason, wasnt sure.